# Asymptotic analysis of coefficients of ordinary generating functions with radius of convergence $1$ seems to always predict polynomial growth rate

Tags: asymptotics, generating-functions

Wikipedia gives the following formula for obtaining asymptotic information about the coefficients of an ordinary generating function from information about the generating function itself: if the generating function $G(a_n;x)$ is such that $$G(a_n;x)={A(x)+B(x)(1-\frac xr)^{-\beta}\over x^\alpha}$$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ where $r$ is the radius of convergence of $G(a_n;x)$ and $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are either entire or analytic to a radius of convergence strictly greater than $r$, then $$a_n \sim \frac{B(r)n^{\beta-1}}{r^{n+\alpha}\Gamma(\beta)}.$$ Suppose that $r=1$. Won't this always give an estimate of the form $$a_n\sim c_1n^{c_2}$$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$? Clearly this cannot be true, since the generating function of many sequences not asymptotic to a polynomial has radius of convergence $1$.

Comment: That $G$ is very particular.  Not all functions with radius of convergence $1$ look like it.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, but many do; certainly it's possible to construct a sequence whose generating function has radius of convergence $1$ but which is not asymptotic to a polynomial.

Comment: Right, so the theorem is saying that generating functions which **do** look like $G$ have polynomially growing coefficients.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Is there a good way of determining which generating functions can be so expressed? It seems to me that the main difficulty is in proving that the limit $\lim_{x\to 1} G(a_n;x)(1-x)^\beta$ exists for some $\beta$, but I don't see how to prove it. If so, could you make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be a shortcut, no.  That limit existing isn't sufficient since $G$ could have other, dominating singularities elsewhere on the unit circle.  There are weaker conditions you could check though (e.g. $x^\alpha (1-x)^\beta G(x)$ being analytic on $|x| < 1+\epsilon$).

Comment: @AntonioVargas You're right; I was thinking in particular of generating functions with a single pole at $1$.